# RSA Key only seems to contain its memory address. Swift, MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, rsa

I am currently trying to generate a CSR for a mac app, and have narrowed down an issue within my key generation.

I am currently using the code below to generate the keys, which for the most part works. However, from a lot of the references I have been using, the expected output should be along the lines of:

<SecKeyRef algorithm id: 1, key type: RSAPrivateKey, version: 4, block size: 2048 bits, addr: 0x600001ae74c0>

However, on checking the SecKeyRef output in debug after key generation, all I get is this:

<SecKeyRef: 0x600000cbd6e0>

I suspect this is the reason when I check the CSR out put on Red Kestrel that the key size is 0 and the CSR signature can't be read.

Just wondering if this might be why?

```
        let publicKeyParameters: [String: Any] = [
        String(kSecAttrIsPermanent): true,
        String(kSecAttrAccessible): kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock,
        String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): tagPublic.data(using: .utf8)!
    ]

    let privateKeyParameters: [String: Any] = [
        String(kSecAttrIsPermanent): true,
        String(kSecAttrAccessible): kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock,
        String(kSecAttrKeySizeInBits): 2048,
        String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): tagPrivate.data(using: .utf8)!
    ]

    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        String(kSecAttrKeyType): algorithm.secKeyAttrType,
        String(kSecAttrKeySizeInBits): keySize,
        String(kSecReturnRef): true,
        String(kSecPublicKeyAttrs): publicKeyParameters,
        String(kSecPrivateKeyAttrs): privateKeyParameters
    ]

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(parameters as CFDictionary, &error)
```

Comment: Isn't that just the debug description?

Comment: Yeah, it is. But when I am decoding the CSR I generate, it does seem to be missing the info shown in the expected output, block size being one of them.